# Twitter: "This page contains too many server redirects" error

Tags: java, android, twitter

I'm trying to share some data using twitter in android app, so what ever the basic information like redirecting url, application given in the "Twitter app registration page", everything works fine but after giving the username and password in the LOGIN PAGE of twitter it doesn't redirects to the next page, instead getting "this page contains too many server redirects" error message.

My redirect url looks like this `"https://www.example.com/"`.

Any suggestions?

```
public class constants {
public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "key";
public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET= "secret";

public static final String REQUEST_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";
public static final String ACCESS_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
public static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";


public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = "x-latify-oauth-twitter";
private static final String CALLBACK_SCHEME = null;
public static final Object OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://callback";
```

}

MainActivity

```
import java.util.Date;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
   import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {


private SharedPreferences prefs;
  private final Handler mTwitterHandler = new Handler();
  private TextView loginStatus;

    final Runnable mUpdateTwitterNotification = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tweet sent !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  };

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    loginStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ls);
    Button tweet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tweet);
    Button clearCredentials = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cc);

      tweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     * to the twitter login page. Once the user authenticated, he'll authorize the     Android     application to send
    * tweets on the users behalf.
    */
        public void onClick(View v) {
         if (TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs)) {
         sendTweet();
         } else {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrepareRequestTokenActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("tweet_msg",getTweetMsg());
    startActivity(i);
         }
        }
    });

    clearCredentials.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         clearCredentials();
         updateLoginStatus();
        }
    });
   }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 updateLoginStatus();
  }

 public void updateLoginStatus() {
  loginStatus.setText("Logged into Twitter : " + TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(prefs));
  }


 private String getTweetMsg() {
 return "Tweeting from Android App at " + new Date().toLocaleString();
  } 

 public void sendTweet() {
 Thread t = new Thread() {
  public void run() {

  try {
  TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs,getTweetMsg());
  mTwitterHandler.post(mUpdateTwitterNotification);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  }

 };
 t.start();
 }

 private void clearCredentials() {
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
 edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN);
 edit.remove(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET);
 edit.commit();
 }
 }



import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
 import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.util.Log;


public class OAuthRequestTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private Context context;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;

    /**
    *
    * We pass the OAuth consumer and provider.
    *
    * @param context
    * Required to be able to start the intent to launch the browser.
    * @param provider
    * The OAuthProvider object
    * @param consumer
    * The OAuthConsumer object
    */
    public OAuthRequestTokenTask(Context context,OAuthConsumer consumer,OAuthProvider provider) {
    this.context = context;
    this.consumer = consumer;
    this.provider = provider;
    }

    /**
    *
    * Retrieve the OAuth Request Token and present a browser to the user to authorize the token.
    *
    */
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
    Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving request token from Google servers");
    final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
    Log.i(TAG, "Popping a browser with the authorize URL : " + url);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error during OAUth retrieve request token", e);
    }

    return null;
    }

    }




import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
import android.util.Log;
import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;

 public class PrepareRequestTokenActivity extends Activity {
final String TAG = getClass().getName();

private OAuthConsumer consumer;
private OAuthProvider provider;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 try {
 this.consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(constants.CONSUMER_KEY,    constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
 this.provider = new          CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(constants.REQUEST_URL,constants.ACCESS_URL,constants.AUTHORIZE_URL      );
 } catch (Exception e) {
 Log.e(TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider",e);
 }

    Log.i(TAG, "Starting task to retrieve request token.");
  new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this,consumer,provider).execute();
  }

  /**
  * Called when the OAuthRequestTokenTask finishes (user has authorized the request    token).
 * The callback URL will be intercepted here.
  */
 @Override
     public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   final Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
   Log.i(TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
    Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");
    new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this,consumer,provider,prefs).execute(uri);
     finish();  
     }
      }

          public class RetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {

       private Context  context;
      private OAuthProvider provider;
      private OAuthConsumer consumer;
       private SharedPreferences prefs;

     public RetrieveAccessTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer                   consumer,OAuthProvider provider, SharedPreferences prefs) {
   this.context = context;
     this.consumer = consumer;
    this.provider = provider;
     this.prefs=prefs;
        }


      /**
       * Retrieve the oauth_verifier, and store the oauth and oauth_token_secret
     * for future API calls.
       */
      protected Void doInBackground(Uri...params) {
        final Uri uri = params[0];
      final String oauth_verifier = uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

             try {
       provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

      final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
         edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
       edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, consumer.getTokenSecret());
     edit.commit();

     String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
     String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

     consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
     context.startActivity(new Intent(context,MainActivity.class));

  executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval();

   Log.i(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieved");

    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
     }

   return null;
      }


     private void executeAfterAccessTokenRetrieval() {
     String msg = getIntent().getExtras().getString("tweet_msg");
     try {
      TwitterUtils.sendTweet(prefs, msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Error sending to Twitter", e);
     }
     }
    }
```

twitterUtils.java

```
import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
 import twitter4j.TwitterException;
 import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
 import twitter4j.http.AccessToken;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;

  public class TwitterUtils {
public static boolean isAuthenticated(SharedPreferences prefs) {

 String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
 String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

 AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
 Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
 twitter.setOAuthConsumer(constants.CONSUMER_KEY, constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
 twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);

 try {
 twitter.getAccountSettings();
 return true;
 } catch (TwitterException e) {
 return false;
 }
 }

 public static void sendTweet(SharedPreferences prefs,String msg) throws Exception {
 String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
 String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

 AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);
 Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
 twitter.setOAuthConsumer(constants.CONSUMER_KEY, constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
  twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(a);
    twitter.updateStatus(msg);
 }  
 }
```

Comment: Post some code so we can help you more.

Comment: added constants.java code@DipakKeshariya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your Call Back URL and write below Call back URL instead of your URL.

```
public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-twitter://callback";
```

And see below link for more information.

[Twitter Integration in Android](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-android.html)

Comment: @DDA Try Above link example of Twitter Integration.

Comment: @DDA If you don't have any issue use above link code, it will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: yes i had downloaded n testing that, vry nice tutorial, l implement that in my project, if i get the output surely vl make ur answer correct:)@Dipak Keshariya

Comment: @DDA In above link code write your next activity code in onComplete() method of mTwitterLoginDialogListener and try.

Comment: i'm getting error in TwitterActivity.java of ur code, in this class private void postAsToast(FROM twitterPost, MESSAGE success)@Dipak Keshariya

Comment: The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, String, int)@Dipak Keshariya

Comment: Dipak everything went fine, but after giving username and password, m getting forceclose...@Dipak Keshariya

Comment: @DDA Post Error logcat in your question or post another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378470/twitter-after-giving-username-and-password-the-app-gets-crash@Dipak Keshariya

Comment: @DDA Accept this answer and Are you using my whole code without changes?

Comment: i had posted the seperate question based on ur link, i followed ur link only,  l accept ur answer there, coz for many of the users it will be helpful...@Dipak Keshariya

Comment: this is the best tutorial for integrating twitter... pls find this friends, http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-android.html

Comment: i did its getting working, but after copy pasting it in my project, getting force close, u told previously to include some code in Oncompletemethod of some class na,,, wat shud i give in that class?@Dipak Keshariya